# Accessing Joomla Enviroment script fails if not in root

Tags: php, joomla, external

I'm a newbie but trying to learn.

I have a script to read the joomla user details. It's a simple script just to display logged in user name. The script works if I put it in the root directory of my website.

What I want to do is run the script from a folder off the root, /ssscart, for example.

When I put the script in the sub-directory it does not execute.

Here is my script:

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );
define( 'DS', '/' );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

JFactory::getApplication('site')->initialise();

$user = JFactory::getUser();
$joomla_name = $user->name;
$joomla_email = $user->email;
$joomla_password = $user->password;
$joomla_username = $user->username;
echo 'hello';
echo " - ".$joomla_username;
?>
```

I believe my problem is in the JPATH_BASE entry but haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Thanks

G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

The is issue is due to `JPATH_BASE` path getting wrongly.

when you are in root it will look like.

`define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );`

So in your case you are in sub folder so it will be look like.

`define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) );`

so your final code will be look like.

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) );
define( 'DS', '/' );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

JFactory::getApplication('site')->initialise();
```

Hope it works..

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you were right on the button. Thanks so much.